# jQuery, Object has no method 'innerHtml'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I asked a question a bit back and got some useful advice. I am trying to make a sortable list that allows the user to add a youtube url to the list. I have it set to take the id and put it in an array, I then want it to use the following javascript to append the video url and a "cue" link to the list:

```
    _videoId = _videoUrl.replace(/^[^v]+v.(.{11}).*/,"$1");
//place the Videoid in an array
_videoList[_videoList.length] = _videoId;
var $new_element = document.createElement('li');
//set the id of the li element to match it's position in the array
var refId = _videoList.length;
$new_element = $('li').attr('id', refId);
var $link = $('a')
.attr('href', _videoUrl)
.innerHtml(_videoUrl)
.data('refId', refId) // add parent li's id for reference in click event
.appendTo( $new_element )
.bind( 'click', function(){
    cue( $link.data('refId') );
    return false; // prevent browser's default click event
});

$new_element.appendTo( container );
```

However it is giving me an error (in chrome)

> Object [object Object] has no method 'innerHtml'

my HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="hostPanel">
        <div id="videoList">
        <ul id="sortable">

        </ul>
        </div>
```

Any help on getting this to work could be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

innerHtml is a property of DOM-elements, not a method of jQuery-objects. Use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead.

---

**Edit:**

Regarding to the comment:

```
$new_element = $('li').attr('id', refId);
```

This doesn't create a new `<li>`-element, it takes the existing `<li>`-elements inside the document.

To create a new element in jQuery use

```
$new_element = $('<li/>').attr('id', refId);
```

It's the same here:

```
var $link = $('a')
```

...has to be

```
var $link = $('<a/>')
```

Don't mix jQuery and Javascript(DOM)

This is the Javascript(DOM)-way to create an element:

```
var $new_element = document.createElement('li');
```

jQuery expects markup for `$()` while the DOM-method `createElement()` expects a tagName as parameter .

Comment: Yes, that stopped the error, however the new list element is not showing up. I'm a bit new to JS and JQuery. So forgive me if I ask simple questions.